# Uncomment closing accolade via sed

Tags: regex, linux, awk, sed

I want to use `sed` to uncomment and change a few lines in my ngnix config

This..

```
...
# location ~ \.php$ {
#   include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
#   # With php-cgi (or other tcp sockets):
#   fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
#   # With php-fpm (or other unix sockets):
#   fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
# }
...
```

..should become this:

```
...
location ~ \.php$ {
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
#   # With php-cgi (or other tcp sockets):
#   fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
#   # With php-fpm (or other unix sockets):
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock;
}
...
```

Here is what I used to uncomment the first three lines:

```
sudo sed -i 's/#\s*location ~ \\\.php$ {/location ~ \\.php$ {/g' /etc/nginx/sites-available/default
sudo sed -i 's/#\s*include snippets\/fastcgi-php\.conf;/\tinclude snippets\/fastcgi-php.conf;/g' /etc/nginx/sites-available/default
sudo sed -i 's/#\s*fastcgi_pass unix:\/run\/php\/php7\.0-fpm\.sock;/\tfastcgi_pass unix:\/run\/php\/php7\.1-fpm.sock;/g' /etc/nginx/sites-available/default
```

I managed to get these lines to work but I'm not sure how to uncomment the closing accolade without uncommenting the others in the rest of the file as well. Any thoughts on how to approach this?

**Solution**

Thanks to Wintermute's answer I managed to get things working. Here is my final solution all packed in one single command line:

```
sudo sed -i '/^\s*#\s*location ~ \\\.php\$ {/ {
    :loop /\n\s*#\s*}/! {
        N;
        b loop;
    };
    s@#@@;
    s@#\(\s*include snippets/fastcgi-php\.conf;\)@\1@;
    s@#\(\s*fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7\.\)[0-9]\+\(-fpm\.sock;\)@\11\2@;
    s@\n\(\s*\)#\(\s*}\)@\n\1\2@;
};' /etc/nginx/sites-available/default
```

Comment: Doesn't `^#\s*}\s*$` work? You have some semantic errors in your regex too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the config file probably contains much more thas this one section, false matches are a problem to consider here. In particular, matching `^#\s*}` and hoping for the best is liable to uncomment completely unrelated lines somewhere else in the file.

Because of this, I'd collect all lines that belong the section in question before uncommenting. I'm thinking along the lines of this: Put the code

```
/^#\s*location ~ \\\.php\$ {/ {
  :loop
  /\n#\s*}/! {
    N
    b loop
  }
  s/^#//
  s@#\(\s*include snippets/fastcgi-php\.conf;\)@\1@
  s@#\(\s*fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7\.\)0\(-fpm\.sock;\)@\11\2@
  s/\n#\(\s*}\)/\n\1/
}
```

into a file, say `uncomment.sed`, then run

```
sed -f uncomment.sed /etc/nginx/sites-available/default
```

If the result satisfies you, add the `-i` option to edit in place.

This code works as follows:

```
/^#\s*location ~ \\\.php\$ {/ {    # starting with the first line of the section
                                   # (regex taken from the question):
  :loop                            # jump label for looping
  /\n#\s*}/! {                     # Until the last line is in the pattern space
    N                              # fetch the next line from input, append it
    b loop                         # then loop
  }

  # At this point, we have the whole section in the pattern space.
  # Time to remove the comments.

  # There's a # at the beginning of the pattern space; remove it. This
  # uncomments the first line.
  s/^#//

  # The middle two are taken from the question, except I'm using @ as 
  # a separator so I don't have to escape all those slashes and captures
  # to avoid repeating myself.
  s@#\(\s*include snippets/fastcgi-php\.conf;\)@\1@
  s@#\(\s*fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7\.\)0\(-fpm\.sock;\)@\11\2@

  # Uncomment the last line. Note that we can't use ^ here because that
  # refers to the start of the pattern space. However, because of the
  # looping construct above, we know there's only one # directly after
  # a newline followed by \s*} in it, and that's the comment sign before
  # the last line. So remove that, and we're done.
  s/\n#\(\s*}\)/\n\1/
}
```

Comment: I get `uncomment.sed line 4: extra characters after command` so somthing seems to be wrong with the `N` line.

Comment: Huh, odd; it works for me. Which version of sed are you using? I tested with GNU sed 4.4.

Comment: I have 4.2.2 and no clue how to update `sed is already the newest version (4.2.2-7).` (Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS)

Comment: I have a machine that has sed 4.2.2 (debian jessie), for me it works there too. Maybe a character got lost in transfer or something? I don't really see anything nefarious in that script that could work with some versions of GNU sed and not others. :/ Side note: I updated the code a little because I only just noticed you wanted to replace 7.0 with 7.1, but that's a separate issue and is unlikely to fix this error.

Comment: I managed to get it working thanks to this post: https://superuser.com/questions/318439/sed-error-sed-e-expression-1-char-extra-characters-after-command/318441?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa
Apparently there need to be a `;` at the end of each line. Not sure why it works for you without them though.

Comment: I also squeezed everything in to a single command line (see original post) so I have no need for a separate .sed file :)

Comment: Ah, that explains it. Commands are separated by semicolons or newlines, so if you take away one, you'll have to use the other.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative `gnu-awk` solution with a custom `RS`:

```
awk -v RS='# location [^{]*{[^}]*}\n' 'RT {
   RT = gensub(/(^|\n)[[:blank:]]*#([[:blank:]]*(location|include|fastcgi_pass unix|}))/, "\\1\\2", "g", RT)
   RT = gensub(/(php7\.)0/, "\\11", "1", RT)
}
{ORS=RT} 1' file
```

```
...
 location ~ \.php$ {
   include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
#   # With php-cgi (or other tcp sockets):
#   fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
#   # With php-fpm (or other unix sockets):
   fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock;
 }
...
```

**References:**

- [Effective AWK Programming](https://www.gnu.org/s/gawk/manual/gawk.pdf)
- [Awk Tutorial](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html)

Comment: Ah I see it now. Thanks for your helpful comment, it is edited now.